# How to get next page from Okta api call with CURL

Tags: pagination, okta

Im currently querying Okta for a list of events. The result set is tens of thousands. Currently the requests limits the return to 1000 results. Per the Okta API. http://developer.okta.com/docs/getting_started/design_principles.html#pagination  I can use the Link header with the value "next".

How do I use CURL to capture this value and issue that CURL command on that URL to get the rest of the values and loop till the end?

Answer (score 3):

In cURL, if you include the include '-i' option, the headers are returned to the console. Within these headers, you'll find a link called rel="next". If you replace the resource in the first GET call with this filter, you'll get the next set of results.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `-D filename` to get the returned headers in a separate file rather than at the top of your output file.

Comment: @Benjamin Wesson - How does one loop through the GET request via curl?

Answer (score 0):

The pagination code is based on https://michaelheap.com/follow-github-link-header-bash

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set these:
url="https://COMPANY.okta.com/api/v1/users"
token="..."

# Pagination code based on https://michaelheap.com/follow-github-link-header-bash
while [ "$url" ]; do
    r=$(curl --compressed -Ss -i -H "authorization: SSWS $token" "$url" | tr -d '\r')
    echo "$r" | sed '1,/^$/d' | jq -r '.[].profile.login'
    url=$(echo "$r" | sed -n -E 's/link: <(.*)>; rel="next"/\1/pi')
done
```

Note that if you're making multiple requests (which you probably are, since you're paginating), using a language like Python with the `requests` package is much faster than curl. A requests `session` will keep the connection open, whereas curl closes it and reopens it every time.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

# Set these:
url = 'https://COMPANY.okta.com/api/v1/users'
token = '...'

# If you're making multiple API calls, using a session is much faster.
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['authorization'] = 'SSWS ' + token

def get_objects(url):
    while url:
        r = session.get(url)
        for o in r.json():
            yield o
        url = r.links.get('next', {}).get('url')
        
for user in get_objects(url):
    print(user['profile']['login'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This version of the shell script has better variable names to make it easier to understand.

As in the other comment, running `curl` with the `-i` or `--include` option includes the response headers.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set these:
url='https://COMPANY.okta.com/api/v1/users'
token='...'

# Pagination code based on https://michaelheap.com/follow-github-link-header-bash
auth="authorization: SSWS $token"
while [ "$url" ]; do
    res=$(curl --compressed -isSH "$auth" "$url" | tr -d '\r')
    headers=$(echo "$res" | sed '/^$/q')
    body=$(echo "$res" | sed '1,/^$/d')
    echo "$body" | jq -r '.[].profile.login'
    url=$(echo "$headers" | sed -n -E 's/link: <(.*)>; rel="next"/\1/pi')
done
```