# How do you paginate with Okta API call?

Tags: bash, curl, pagination, okta

Sorry for the stupid question but I saw this thread from 7 years ago but am wondering how to do the same thing:

[How to get next page from Okta api call with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307083/how-to-get-next-page-from-okta-api-call-with-curl)

I see the '-i' flag to pass to curl to get the "next" URL but I'm still not entirely sure how to loop through the subsequent URLs provided in the header until there no further results to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The pagination code is based on https://michaelheap.com/follow-github-link-header-bash/

```bash
# Set these:
url="https://COMPANY.okta.com/api/v1/users"
token="..."

# Pagination code based on https://michaelheap.com/follow-github-link-header-bash/
while [ "$url" ]; do
    r=$(curl --compressed -Ss -i -H "authorization: SSWS $token" "$url" | tr -d '\r')
    echo "$r" | sed '1,/^$/d' | jq -r '.[].profile.login'
    url=$(echo "$r" | sed -n -E 's/link: <(.*)>; rel="next"/\1/pi')
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This version of the shell script has better variable names to make it easier to understand.

As you posted in your question, running `curl` with the `-i` or `--include` option includes the response headers.

I posted the same update on [How to get next page from Okta api call with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307083/how-to-get-next-page-from-okta-api-call-with-curl) along with a Python version and an explanation of why you might want to use Python instead of curl.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set these:
url='https://COMPANY.okta.com/api/v1/users'
token='...'

# Pagination code based on https://michaelheap.com/follow-github-link-header-bash
auth="authorization: SSWS $token"
while [ "$url" ]; do
    res=$(curl --compressed -isSH "$auth" "$url" | tr -d '\r')
    headers=$(echo "$res" | sed '/^$/q')
    body=$(echo "$res" | sed '1,/^$/d')
    echo "$body" | jq -r '.[].profile.login'
    url=$(echo "$headers" | sed -n -E 's/link: <(.*)>; rel="next"/\1/pi')
done
```